# PhoneGap Build Settings in Dreamweaver

Tags: cordova, dreamweaver

Apologies in advance.
When I go into Site, PhoneGap Build Service, PhoneGap Build Settings, it asks:

> To enable emulation, please provide the root paths to the following
>   sdks.

```
Android SDK Location
webOS SDK Location
```

Q: What does that mean?
I downloaded phonegap-phonegap-2.2.0-0-g8a3aa47.zip from PhoneGap.com, but I don't understand what Dreamweaver is looking for.

Feel free to tell me to read the manual if you give me a link to the manual.

Answer (score 3):

You have to download Android SDK from [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem when I begun to developing my first app on Phonegap.
After some time research I found this video and it saved my life.

Please take a look:
http://tv.adobe.com/watch/cs-55-web-premium-feature-tour-/dreamweaver-cs-55-creating-a-native-mobile-application/

If you use Windows OS and Android emulator I think that you will need to know how to install the .apk file on emulator http://www.botskool.com/geeks/how-install-apk-files-android-windows-sdk-emulator